# Pluck and transform array in point-free style

Tags: ramda.js

I have an array of objects and another mapper object.

```
const arr = [{id: 'email_sha256', name: 'email'}, {id: 'phone', name: 'phone number'}]
const mapper = {email_sha256: 'email', email_sha_256: 'email'}
```

I want to get the array of ids but if id value is present in mapper , then it should be transformed to the corresponding value in mapper. For example, the output of above array -

```
['email', 'phone']
```

My approach -

```
export const mapToId = compose(
  uniq,
  map((op) => mapper[op.id] ?? op.id)
)
```

How can this be done in a better way with ramda?

Comment: `map((op) => mapper[op.id] ?? op.id)` — That's pretty decent already.

Comment: Why do you think point-free would be better?  That looks like a clean solution already.

Answer (score 1):

We can write a `pluckMap` function that takes a list of objects and for each object extract the value at given key and applies a function to it.

The function in this case is `rename`:

```js
const rename = curry((m, k) => m[k] || k);
```

`m` is a map and `k` is a key. Returns `m[k]` or `k` if not found.

Then `pluckMap`:

```js
const pluckMap = curry((k, fn, xs) => xs.map(x => fn(x[k])));
```

So now we can do:

```js
const extract = pluckMap('id', rename({ email_sha256:  'email'
                                      , email_sha_256: 'email'}));

extract([ {id: 'email_sha256', name: 'email'       }
        , {id: 'phone'       , name: 'phone number'}]);

//=> ["email", "phone"]
```